# Como deletar as noticias do banco MySQL?

Tags: java, android, mysql, json

[Neste link](http://www.mybringback.com/tutorial-series/13239/android-mysql-php-json-part-6-json-parsing-and-android-design/) ensina a listar comentários (no meu caso noticias) usando banco de dados externo (tem o download do projeto).

Como posso deletar uma notícia ao selecionar, e ainda fazer com que apareça um Dialog perguntando se quero ou não deletar a noticia do banco de dados externo?

Esse é o código do `INSERT`:

```
public void chamaCadastrarNoticia(){
    setContentView(R.layout.cadastrar_noticia);

    editTituloNoticia=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTituloNoticia);
    editNoticia=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editNoticia);
    btCadastrarNoticia=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btCadastrarNoticia);

    btCadastrarNoticia.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {                
            String vazios = "";
            if (editTituloNoticia.getText().toString().equals("")) 
                vazios="Campo Titulo não pode estar vazio\n\n"; 

            if (editNoticia.getText().toString().equals("")) 
                vazios="Campo Noticia não pode estar vazio\n\n";            

            if  (editTituloNoticia.getText().toString().equals("") || editNoticia.getText().toString().equals("")) 
                mensagemExibir("Erro:", ""+vazios);
            else {                
                String urlPost="#url"; // URL
                String urlGet="#url   ?titulo="+editTituloNoticia.getText().toString()+"noticia="+editNoticia.getText().toString(); // URL
                ArrayList<NameValuePair> iparametrosPost = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                iparametrosPost.add(new BasicNameValuePair("titulo",editTituloNoticia.getText().toString()));   
                iparametrosPost.add(new BasicNameValuePair("noticia",editNoticia.getText().toString()));            
                String respostaRetornada = null;

                try {
                    respostaRetornada = ConexaoHttpClient.executaHttpPost(urlPost, iparametrosPost);
                    String resposta = respostaRetornada.toString();
                    resposta = resposta.replaceAll("\\s+", "");

                    if (resposta.equals("1")) {
                        mensagemExibir("Cadastrado:", "Acesse Listar Noticias para ver a noticia cadastrada");
                    }

                    chamaIndexAdmin();
                }
                catch(Exception erro){
                    Log.i("erro", "erro = "+erro);
                    mensagemExibir("Erro", "Erro ao gravar: "+erro);
                }
            }
        }
    });     
}
```

Comment: vc ja conseguiu fazer o `INSERT`?

Comment: sim, quero usar esse projeto para listar noticias(deu certo) mas nao consigo implementar para excluir elas

Comment: tem como vc me mostrar como faz para deletar do banco de dados, usando esse projeto la?  la tem para baixar

Comment: acho que eu nao vou precisar baixar; sua pergunta está um pouco ampla, mas se vc ja conseguiu fazer o insert o delete é mt parecido, poderia nos mostrar como vc faz o insert? edite sua pergunta para inserir o código

Comment: nao fiz o insert usando o projeto la, fiz uma mistura, porderia fazer separado mas preciso resolver com urgencia esse problema, quando baixei o projeto, consegui listar ai juntei o codigo com meu projeto antigo

Comment: la msm o cara fala que pode usar o onItemClick para futuras modificações mas ele nao ensina a deletar =(

Comment: pera minto, fiz o INSERT no meu projeto, vou enviar

Comment: @Math olha la na pergunta o codigo do INSERT

Comment: o codigo é totalmente diferente, nao uso JSON no codigo do insert

Comment: ajuda ai pessoal =(

Answer (score 2):

Para fazer apresentar uma confirmação para o usuário você poderá utilizar o [Dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html), colocando uma requisição ao servidor no botão de positivo.

Para deletar um comentário ( notícia, no seu caso ), acredito que a melhor opção seja criar um novo serviço ( removeComment.php, por exemplo ) que será chamado e passar como parâmetro algum identificador da notícia ( recomendo ser o próprio identificador da tabela do banco de dados )

A partir daí é só atualizar a lista no dispositivo

Comment: no meu caso criei o excluirNoticias.php mas tento implementar a função de excluir la no OnItemClick e sempre da erro. tem como vc baixar o projeto la e me mostrar como se faz? la so mostra pra listar, agora excluir nao =(  semana passada fez 1 mês que estou tentando e nada, me ajuda